# Custom .htaccess mobile redirection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mobile, url-rewriting

I am trying to redirect specific pages to other specific pages only when the user is accessing the website via a mobile device. So far, I have the code below, but it is not working and I am unsure as to why. Please advise.

```
#=== Start Mobile Redirection ===
# Check if this is the noredirect query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)noredirect=true(&|$)
# Set a cookie, and skip the next rule
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mredir:0:%{HTTP_HOST},S]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "acs|alav|alca|amoi|audi|aste|avan|benq|bird|blac|blaz|brew|cell|cldc|cmd-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "dang|doco|eric|hipt|inno|ipaq|java|jigs|kddi|keji|leno|lg-c|lg-d|lg-g|lge-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  "maui|maxo|midp|mits|mmef|mobi|mot-|moto|mwbp|nec-|newt|noki|opwv" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "palm|pana|pant|pdxg|phil|play|pluc|port|prox|qtek|qwap|sage|sams|sany" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sch-|sec-|send|seri|sgh-|shar|sie-|siem|smal|smar|sony|sph-|symb|t-mo" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "teli|tim-|tosh|tsm-|upg1|upsi|vk-v|voda|w3cs|wap-|wapa|wapi" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "wapp|wapr|webc|winw|winw|xda|xda-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "up.browser|up.link|windowssce|iemobile|mini|mmp" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "symbian|midp|wap|phone|pocket|mobile|pda|psp" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !macintosh [NC]

# Can not read and write cookie in same request, must duplicate condition
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)noredirect=true(&|$) 

# Check to make sure we haven't set the cookie before
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}        !^.*noredirect=true.*$ [NC]

# Now redirect to the mobile site
RewriteRule ^/index/albums/review(.*)$ /index/mobile/album$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^/index/albums/upcoming(.*)$ /index/mobile/albums-upcoming$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^/index/albums(.*)$ /index/mobile/albums$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^/index/artists/info(.*)$ /index/mobile/artist$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^/index/hip-hop/best(.*)$ /index/mobile/best$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^/index/music-charts/albums(.*)$ /index/mobile/chart-albums$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^/index/music-charts/entry(.*)$ /index/mobile/chart$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^/index/music-charts(.*)$ /index/mobile/charts$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^/index/hip-hop/downloads(.*)$ /index/mobile/downloads$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^/index/news/entry(.*)$ /index/mobile/feature$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^/index/news(.*)$ /index/mobile/features$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^/index/mixtapes/entry(.*)$ /index/mobile/mixtape$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^/index/mixtapes(.*)$ /index/mobile/mixtapes$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^/index/playlists/entry(.*)$ /index/mobile/playlist$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^/index/playlists(.*)$ /index/mobile/playlists$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^/index/tracks/review(.*)$ /index/mobile/track$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^/index/tracks(.*)$ /index/mobile/tracks$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /index/mobile/ [R,L]

#=== End mobile Redirection ===
```

EDIT: Final solution posted here. Thanks to Jon Lin

```
#=== Start Mobile Redirection ===
# Check if this is the noredirect query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)noredirect=true(&|$)
# Set a cookie, and skip the next rule
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mredir:0:%{HTTP_HOST},S]

# Can not read and write cookie in same request, must duplicate condition
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)noredirect=true(&|$) [OR]

# Check to make sure we haven't set the cookie before
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}  ^.*noredirect=true.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} ^$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       ^$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !"acs|alav|alca|amoi|audi|aste|avan|benq|bird|blac|blaz|brew|cell|cldc|cmd-" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !"dang|doco|eric|hipt|inno|ipaq|java|jigs|kddi|keji|leno|lg-c|lg-d|lg-g|lge-" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !"maui|maxo|midp|mits|mmef|mobi|mot-|moto|mwbp|nec-|newt|noki|opwv" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !"palm|pana|pant|pdxg|phil|play|pluc|port|prox|qtek|qwap|sage|sams|sany" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !"sch-|sec-|send|seri|sgh-|shar|sie-|siem|smal|smar|sony|sph-|symb|t-mo" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !"teli|tim-|tosh|tsm-|upg1|upsi|vk-v|voda|w3cs|wap-|wapa|wapi" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !"wapp|wapr|webc|winw|winw|xda|xda-" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !"up.browser|up.link|windowssce|iemobile|mini|mmp" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !"symbian|midp|wap|phone|pocket|mobile|pda|psp" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !macintosh [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Now redirect to the mobile site
RewriteRule ^index/albums/review(.*)$ /index/mobile/album$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index/albums/upcoming(.*)$ /index/mobile/albums-upcoming$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index/albums(.*)$ /index/mobile/albums$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index/artists/info(.*)$ /index/mobile/artist$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index/hip-hop/best(.*)$ /index/mobile/best$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index/music-charts/albums(.*)$ /index/mobile/chart-albums$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index/music-charts/entry(.*)$ /index/mobile/chart$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index/music-charts(.*)$ /index/mobile/charts$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index/hip-hop/downloads(.*)$ /index/mobile/downloads$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index/news/entry(.*)$ /index/mobile/feature$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index/news(.*)$ /index/mobile/features$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index/mixtapes/entry(.*)$ /index/mobile/mixtape$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index/mixtapes(.*)$ /index/mobile/mixtapes$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index/playlists/entry(.*)$ /index/mobile/playlist$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index/playlists(.*)$ /index/mobile/playlists$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index/tracks/review(.*)$ /index/mobile/track$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index/tracks(.*)$ /index/mobile/tracks$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(?!index/mobile/)(.*) /index/mobile/ [R,L]

#=== End mobile Redirection ===
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite conditions only apply to the immediately following rewrite rule, which means that all those conditions **only** apply to this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/index/albums/review(.*)$ /index/mobile/album$1 [R,L]
```

and all those other rules you have in your htaccess file has no conditions attached to them. So all requests, mobile or not, will have those rules apply to them.

Instead of duplicating that huge block for all of your rules, you can negate the condition and do a passthrough. Additionally, you want to remove the leading slash from your rule's regexes.

```
#=== Start Mobile Redirection ===
# Check if this is the noredirect query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)noredirect=true(&|$)
# Set a cookie, and skip the next rule
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mredir:0:%{HTTP_HOST},S]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} macintosh [NC,OR]

# Can not read and write cookie in same request, must duplicate condition
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)noredirect=true(&|$) [OR]

# Check to make sure we haven't set the cookie before
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}  ^.*noredirect=true.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} ^$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       ^$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !"acs|alav|alca|amoi|audi|aste|avan|benq|bird|blac|blaz|brew|cell|cldc|cmd-" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !"dang|doco|eric|hipt|inno|ipaq|java|jigs|kddi|keji|leno|lg-c|lg-d|lg-g|lge-" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !"maui|maxo|midp|mits|mmef|mobi|mot-|moto|mwbp|nec-|newt|noki|opwv" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !"palm|pana|pant|pdxg|phil|play|pluc|port|prox|qtek|qwap|sage|sams|sany" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !"sch-|sec-|send|seri|sgh-|shar|sie-|siem|smal|smar|sony|sph-|symb|t-mo" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !"teli|tim-|tosh|tsm-|upg1|upsi|vk-v|voda|w3cs|wap-|wapa|wapi" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !"wapp|wapr|webc|winw|winw|xda|xda-" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !"up.browser|up.link|windowssce|iemobile|mini|mmp" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !"symbian|midp|wap|phone|pocket|mobile|pda|psp" [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Now redirect to the mobile site
RewriteRule ^index/albums/review(.*)$ /index/mobile/album$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index/albums/upcoming(.*)$ /index/mobile/albums-upcoming$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index/albums(.*)$ /index/mobile/albums$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index/artists/info(.*)$ /index/mobile/artist$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index/hip-hop/best(.*)$ /index/mobile/best$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index/music-charts/albums(.*)$ /index/mobile/chart-albums$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index/music-charts/entry(.*)$ /index/mobile/chart$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index/music-charts(.*)$ /index/mobile/charts$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index/hip-hop/downloads(.*)$ /index/mobile/downloads$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index/news/entry(.*)$ /index/mobile/feature$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index/news(.*)$ /index/mobile/features$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index/mixtapes/entry(.*)$ /index/mobile/mixtape$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index/mixtapes(.*)$ /index/mobile/mixtapes$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index/playlists/entry(.*)$ /index/mobile/playlist$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index/playlists(.*)$ /index/mobile/playlists$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index/tracks/review(.*)$ /index/mobile/track$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index/tracks(.*)$ /index/mobile/tracks$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index/mobile/ [R,L]

#=== End mobile Redirection ===
```

Essentially, we've negated the conditions, and if any of them pass, we know it's not mobile.

Comment: Okay thank you for your help. I have removed the leading slashes (also edited your answer to remove them as well) and now it says that the page has a redirect loop and redirects to "/index/mobile"

I'm guessing this is happening because it is hitting that last RewriteRule even though it should be stopping when it hits the first one. 

For reference, I am trying this url: /index/tracks

Comment: @BigBrother6 the rewrite engine will keep looping through all the rules until the URI stops changing (or the internal redirect limit is reached, which causes a 500). Since `(.*)` also matches `/index/mobile`. you're creating an infinite loop. Instead, try: `^(?!index/mobile/)(.*)`

Comment: That worked! You are an absolute lifesaver. Thank you so much.