# .htaccess mobile detect and rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, caching, mobile, detection

I have a problem.

I want to add a mobile detection to my .htaccess. But I don't understand it.

This Code is in my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /


###### Cache ######
# Check if the requested file exists in the cache, otherwise default to index.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/desktop/%{REQUEST_URI}.html !-f
RewriteRule .* - [E=SFC_FILE:/index.php]

# Check if a static file actually exists.
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/desktop/%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f

# Rewrite the request to the static file.
RewriteRule .* %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/desktop/%{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]

###### /Cache ######


RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Change to RewriteBase /cms/ if CMSMS is installed in this subdirectory


# 301 Redirect all requests that don't contain a dot or trailing slash to
# include a trailing slash
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.
#RewriteRule ^(.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

# Rewrites urls in the form of /parent/child/
# but only rewrites if the requested URL is not a file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# COMMENT Monolingual rule and UNCOMMENT MLE rule
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

In the `###### Static Cache ######` part, I want to add the detection. You can see, that there is a `/desktop/` part in the path.
The mobile detection have to redirect to /mobile/.

I found a lot of mobile detections, for example here: [Custom .htaccess mobile redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26369810/custom-htaccess-mobile-redirection)

But I don't understand how combine it with my code.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you already using something to detect mobile browsers, to serve them mobile content to begin with? Is your mobile site on the same domain? If so, how do you store the preference? 0r you you re-detecting the mobile browser every request?

Comment: No, I have no detection. This is what i want to to. The mobile site is in the /mobile/ instead of /desktop/.

The detection is on every request

Comment: So no separate subdomain? How will users switch to the full site if they want to?

Comment: This is not the point. The site is identical, only the critical inline css is different.